# "would not have been happened" vs "would have not been happened"

Tags: meaning-in-context, tense, past-tense, conditional-constructions, negation

Can you please explain me the difference in meanings between these two sentences?

> This would not have been happened if you were not there at that time.
>   This would have not been happened if you were not there at that time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with *have (not) been happened*; it should be *have (not) happened*. As for *wouldn't have ...* vs. *would haven't ...*, please wait for the answers from others. By the way, welcome to ELL!

Comment: Neither is possible. These constructions, with *BE* + *past participle*, are passive; but *happen* is intransitive and cannot be cast in the passive.

Comment: Furthermore, the consequence clause would normally be *if you **had not been** there at that time*.

Comment: Neither of the two sentences are grammatically correct. Where did you "read" these examples? Did someone tell you that these sentences were English?

Answer (score 5):

Neither sentence is grammatical English or something that a native would typically say, so it is pointless to argue over what they might mean. I don't see a reason to correct them differently.

“*This would not <s>have been happened</s>” is a passive construction. But *happen* is not a transitive verb, so it cannot be used in the passive voice. It is likely that the author of this sentence intended to write “This would not have happened”, i.e. the event mentioned previously would not have taken place.

In addition to the previous defect, “*this <s>would have not been</s> happened” is incorrect because the negation cannot be placed where it is. The negation word *not* is normally placed after the first auxiliary: “this would not have …”.

Furthermore, the second part of the sentence is in the wrong tense. “This would have happened” is a past conditional. The part of the sentence introduced by *if* is a past hypothetical. It needs to be in the past tense because the time of the action is in the past; in addition, the hypothetical aspect is expressed by a past tense, which means the verb needs to be in the pluperfect tense: “if you had not been there at that time”.

A correct sentence resembling these two incorrect sentences is

> This would not have happened if you had not been there at that time.

I can't think of a correct sentence with a different meaning that could be what the author was trying to express.